# Custom image upload to Jodit editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, text-editor, jodit

I need to change the process of **uploading an image from computer to Jodit editor to React**. I have already made several attempts to solve this problem, but none worked, this is because I did not understand how the customization of the Jodit uploader works.
Here is my code without any failed attempts:

```
import JoditEditor from 'jodit-react'
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

function JoditComponent({ article, updateArticle }) {
    const editorRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(article, updateArticle)
    }, [article, updateArticle])

    const config = {
        zIndex: 0,
        readonly: false,
        activeButtonsInReadOnly: ['source', 'fullsize', 'print', 'about'],
        toolbarButtonSize: 'middle',
        theme: 'default',
        enableDragAndDropFileToEditor: true,
        saveModeInCookie: false,
        spellcheck: true,
        editorCssClass: false,
        triggerChangeEvent: true,
        height: 450,
        direction: 'ltr',
        language: 'pt_BR',
        debugLanguage: false,
        i18n: 'en',
        tabIndex: -1,
        toolbar: true,
        enter: 'P',
        useSplitMode: false,
        colorPickerDefaultTab: 'background',
        imageDefaultWidth: 100,
        removeButtons: ['about', 'print', 'file'],
        disablePlugins: ['paste', 'stat'],
        events: {},
        textIcons: false,
        uploader: {},
        placeholder: '',
        showXPathInStatusbar: false,
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <JoditEditor
                id='article-content'
                value={article.content}
                ref={editorRef}
                config={config}
                tabIndex={1}
                onChange={(newContent) =>
                    updateArticle({
                        type: 'field',
                        field: 'content',
                        value: newContent,
                    })
                }
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default JoditComponent
```

And here is the process that must be done to send the image to my backend: In the URL `http://localhost:3000/files` a post must be made with the image inside a `formData`. In the return of the request, if everything went well, there will be **only one string inside the response data**, this **string is the URL of access to the image** and must be this URL used in the image to be inserted in Jodit.

Here is a component where the user can choose an image from his computer and it is displayed on the screen (it is just an example):

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Home = () => {
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null)
    const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState(
        'https://st.depositphotos.com/1010338/2099/i/600/depositphotos_20999947-stock-photo-tropical-island-with-palms.jpg'
    )

    const handleFileChange = (event) => {
        setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0])
    }

    const handleUpload = () => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', selectedFile)

        axios
            .post('http://localhost:3000/files', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                setImgUrl(response.data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className='d-flex m-3'>
                <input
                    type='file'
                    onChange={handleFileChange}
                    className='form-control rounded-0 rounded-start'
                />
                <button
                    onClick={handleUpload}
                    className='btn btn-primary rounded-0 rounded-end'
                >
                    Enviar
                </button>
            </div>
            <img
                src={imgUrl}
                alt='Test'
                width={300}
            />
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1):

I think simplest solution is to tweak `uploader`.

This way Jodit handles file selection, sends image to your backend and inserts returned image URL to the editor all by itself:

```
const config={
    // other code
    uploader:{
        insertImageAsBase64URI: false,
        imagesExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif'],
        withCredentials: false,
        format: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/files',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        prepareData: function(data){
            data.append('file', this.file);
            return data;
        },
        isSuccess: function(resp){
            return !resp.error;
        },
        getMsg: function(resp){
            return resp.msg.join !== undefined ? resp.msg.join(' ') : resp.msg;
        },
        process: function(resp){
            return{
                files: [resp.data],
                path: '',
                baseurl: '',
                error: resp.error ? 1 : 0,
                msg: resp.msg
            };
        },
        defaultHandlerSuccess: function(data, resp){
            const files = data.files || [];
            if(files.length){
                this.selection.insertImage(files[0], null, 250);
            }
        },
        defaultHandlerError: function(resp){
            this.events.fire('errorPopap', this.i18n(resp.msg));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not work for me

Comment: Very insightful. Any errors or anything or just "not work"?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting an error

Comment: My backend returns something a string, my object data is a string, is the image's URL. I don't have data.sucesser, data.messages, data.error...